# Show date range for a week in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following code:

```
=UPPER(TEXT(DATE(K2;K1;1+14) + CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(DATE(K2;K1;1)); 1;0;6;5;4;3;2);" \s\e\m\a\n\a d \d\e mmmm \d\e aaaa"))
```

Which displays:

```
SEMANA DE 15 DE SETEMBRO DE 2014
```

But I need to display:

```
SEMANA DE **15-21** DE SETEMBRO DE 2014
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You will not be able to do that, with the BOLD'd dates, without using a VBA Macro.  Excel can only show differential formatting with text strings.  Also, you do not indicate what you want to happen should the contents of K1 and K2 change.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

=SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(TEXT(DATE(K2;K1;1+14) + CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(DATE(K2;K1;1)); 1;0;6;5;4;3;2);" \s\e\m\a\n\a d-""$EOW$"" \d\e mmmm \d\e aaaa"));"$EOW$";DAY(DATE(K2;K1;1+14) + CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(DATE(K2;K1;1)); 1;0;6;5;4;3;2))+6)

I have assumed, that you calculate the first Monday after the 15th of the month and want to show this day and 6 days after.
The idea is to substitute "$EOW$" in the format-string with the day+6.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative approach you could try - should get you the same result

="SEMANA "&22-WEEKDAY(DATE(K2;K1;6))&"-"&28-WEEKDAY(DATE(K2;K1;6))&" DE "&UPPER(TEXT(K1*29;"mmmm"))&"  DE "&K2

Comment: Yea! Calendar weekday arithmetics at its best ;-) 22=15+7 = the maximum day, that can be the next monday after the 15th of the month. And if the weekday of the 6th of the month is sunday (1), then the next mondays are 7,14,21,28. So the next possible monday is 22-1=21... If if the weekday of the 6th of the month is monday (2) , then 22-2=20. If it is tuesday (3), then 22-3=19... If it is saturday (7), then 22-7=15.